# How does 'shrift' connect with the idiom 'short shrift'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Please explain the intuition and connection behind the definition of [shrift](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shrift?q=shrift) and [short shrift](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/short-shrift)?
How does the former imply the latter?

Comment: A *short shrift* was a shrift given to prisoners about to be executed.  It was often brief and clumsy, not in accordance with the usual practices, and thus *short*.  The modern use is a metaphor arising therefrom.

Comment: What @Anonym said...see also the "archaic" use of short shrift in the link you provided

Comment: See the "archaic" sense listed in your second link. The scant time between condemnation and execution would be an occasion for the sacrament of penance, but the sacrament would have to be abbreviated. The contemptuous and dismissive haste associated with "short shrift" comes in this case from the criminal justice system and not from the priest who actually *gives* the shrift.

Comment: Compare Hamlet's forged death warrant for Rosencrantz and Guildenstern, from early in the play's final scene: “An earnest conjuration from the King, / . . . / That on the view, and knowing of these contents, / Without debatement further more or less, / He should those bearers put to sudden death, / Not shriving time allowed.”

Comment: What @AnotherUser and others said. I think the fact that OP's own cited reference for ***short shrift*** has Sense 2: *ARCHAIC Little time between condemnation and execution or punishment* makes this General Reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not necessarily....there is still some jump from there to what Brian said....you need the info from the source, but to put it together is a little more than just what's there

Comment: I think between the comments of @Brian and Anonym we have a good answer

Comment: @AnotherUser: If you honestly think [*linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) could be unable to grasp the connection using just OP's two cited sources, I obviously can't stop you posting an answer. But quite frankly I'd throw this out as GR even on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) - it's not exactly linguistic rocket science.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If he's asking for the "intuition or connection" between the two words, it may not be so clear to some [even serious] "enthusiasts"....have you heard of [expert's curse](http://web.stanford.edu/~phinds/PDFs/Curse-of-Expertise-Hinds99.pdf)?

Comment: @AnotherUser: I didn't know [that particular cognitive bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge) by that name, but I think I can safely say it didn't apply to *me* in this specific context, since until I clicked on OP's two links (which I did before reading any comments) I had no idea what ***shrift*** meant outside the stock phrase ***short shrift***. My reason for *upvoting* (and not closevoting immediately) was *precisely* that I personally didn't originally know the answer. But after looking at the two definitions I can't really see anything meaningful to add.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I apologize for lack of clarity. I was not referring to "expert's curse" regarding the definitions involved in this case, but rather with regards to the ability of a person to extrapolate intuition from facts like these in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the connection is fairly direct, because "short shrift" specifically connotes that someone is impatient with someone else's *excuses*.  So, a priest taking confession in a dismissive way would be a good example of that.  I interpret "short" here in the sense of "less than usual" rather than "lasting a brief time".

Answer (score 1):

as [Anonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/61979/anonym) said in comments

Short Shrift was a shrift given to prisoners about to be executed. It was often brief and clumsy, not in accordance with the usual practices, and thus short.

> It was brief time for [confession](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/short+shrift) or absolution given to a condemned prisoner before his or her execution.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1gc5jc/12_old_words_that_survived_by_getting_fossilized/) which revealed the following answer to my question: see 12 [herefrom](http://www.mentalfloss.com/article/51150/12-old-words-survived-getting-fossilized-idioms).

---

### 12. shrift

We might not know what a shrift is anymore, but we know we don't want to get a short one. "Shrift" was a word for a confession, something it seems we might want to keep short, or a penance imposed by a priest, something we would definitely want to keep short. But the phrase "short shrift" came from the practice of allowing a little time for the condemned to make a confession before being executed. So in that context, shorter was not better.